# NSURLConnection documentation in XCode 4.2.1 doesn't exist for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I recently need to write codes related to "NSURLConnection". But it seems the class reference for this class does not exist in the Documentation in the iOS Doc Set (it exists in the OS X 10.6 Doc Set). (Note: I'm using XCode 4.2.1 with documentation iOS 5.0 Library installed.)

This means when I "Option + click" this class code, it can't take me to the class reference documentation.

By checking on the Internet, I noticed this class reference does exist in 2 doc sets:
[NSURLConnection Class Reference for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-387826)
[NSURLConnection Class Reference for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Is it possible to bring this class reference to my documentation doc set for iOS (so I can option + click to check)? Or is it just my Xcode which suffers from this issue?

**[Edited]**
**Note 1:** 
When Searching NSURLConnection, only the delegate references are returned
**Note 2:** 
The Doc Set checklist is shown below (I only need iOS)
**Note 3:** 
The strange thing is: when I click the "NSURLConnection" hyperlink within the NSURLConnectionDelegate reference article, it does successfully show me the correct NSURLConnection class reference. In other words, its just now shown in the search result. And I can't option-click to read the documentation from the code.
[image]

Comment: Report from Apple Bug Report:

This is a follow up to Bug ID# 10850056.  After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 10722276.

Answer (score 0):

It is available in iOS5.0 docSet. You Xcode might have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you see my updated question. When you search it, can you see it in the search result? (when you test, please make sure the OS X 10.6 Core Library Doc Set is not checked). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the documentation on XCode? 
You should check that. You can find that section by selecting form the menu XCode/Preferences/Downloads/Documentation.
Make sure you have the iOS libraries and the developer library.

Comment: I do have the documentation downloaded. I update my question so you can see it. Thanks